# Running GDB in EMACS

Tags: gdb, fortran

Does anybody know how so use `gdb` in emacs?

I am using this command to create my program

```
/home/cdim/Local/gcc-4.9.2/bin/gfortran -ffree-form -g ./utests/test_gdb.f -o test_gdb
```

I am going to Emacs `Tools` then `Debugger (GDB)`. I then click on the `run` button and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

What does `test_gdb` do if you run it *outside* of gdb? If it sends no output to the screen then this (i.e., no output) is exactly what you will see when you run it *inside* of gdb - if you have set no breakpoints. Did you set a breakpoint? And how much nothing happens when you click `run`? Even if `test_gdb` produces no output, if all is well you should still see gdb display a notification like

```
[Inferior 1 (process 12345) exited normally]
```

Consider `test.f`:

```
  Program p
  Integer :: i = 1
  Print *, i
  End
```

I would compile this with `gfortran -ffree-form -g -ggdb test.f -o test_gdb`.

(From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options:

> -ggdb
>
> Produce debugging information for use by GDB. This means to use the most expressive format available (DWARF 2, stabs, or the native format if neither of those are supported), including GDB extensions if at all possible.

)

Then, as you said, go to `Tools -> Debugger (GDB)` (or issue `M-x gdb`) in emacs and make sure the gdb invocation is using the full path to the executable, e.g. `Run gdb (like this): gdb -i=mi /foo/bar/test_gdb`. Hit return in that minibuffer.

Now, set a breakpoint in the new `*gud-test_gdb*` buffer:

```
(gdb) break p
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4007e1: file test.f, line 3.
```

Then go to menu entry `Gud -> Run`.

Answer (score 0):

**Esc+x** then entern **gdb** ... and input your application file. it will start gdb in emacs

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by moving to Trisquel 7.0. Might have been a setup problem.